# Is it possible to explain sklearn isolation forest prediction?

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I'm using the isolation forest algorithm from sklearn to do some unsupervised anomaly detection. 
I need to explained the predictions and I was wondering if there is any way to get the paths that lead to the decision for each sample.

I usually used SHAP or ELI5 but i'd like to do something more custom. So i need the exact path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use the SHAP values for SkLearn IF : https://github.com/slundberg/shap/pull/784/files

Comment: More info and example of SHAP on IsolationForest here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451518/201327

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an ensemble of trees so and the path of a given instance will be different for each tree in the ensemble. To detect an anomaly the isolation forest takes the average path length (number of splits to isolate a sample) of all the trees for a given instance and uses this to determine if it is an anomaly (average shorter path lengths indicate anomalies). As you are looking at the average of a set of trees there is no 'exact' path.

Within my knowledge, your best bet would be to use something like SHAP, as you mentioned, but you could also train only a few estimators and look at the path taken for a given instance in these trees to get an insight into the decisions.

Comment: Good point. 
Do you know if it's possible to get all the path for a given sample ?

Comment: I believe so: Looking at the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) the fit classifier has a .estimators_ attribute which is a list of the DecisionTreeClassifiers fit. You can then plot / investigate these.